# Репост новостей с сайта в ВКонтакте

Tags: веб-программирование, вконтакте

Репост новостей с сайта в вконтакте, собственно как это можно реализовать, дайте ссылки на мануалы или документацию.

Comment: желательно узнать про репост в группу в контакте а не на стену...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно реализовать используя их [API](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_API). Конкретнее метод [wall.past](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=wall.post).

Для постинга в группу, её ID должен быть задан отрицательным числом: `owner_id=-group_id`

Чтобы сообщение было от имени группы есть такое: `from_group=1`